# Is Runtime.getRuntime().exec() platform independent?

Tags: java, command, runtime, platform, runtime.exec

Is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c");
```

platform independent or I have to pass platform specific command in the parameter?

Thanks

---

What is the linux equivalent of the command `cmd /c start /b java -jar`

Comment: cmd is a windows command ....does not apply to other os

Comment: What you think? Java cannot provide a mapping table as it's just impossible to map between all the different OS'es out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is platform independant in the way, that it will start an external executable on every platform. The executable itself has to be there of course, so starting notepad.exe on Linux will very likely not work (except when you have Wine and Notepad installed, but this is another story).

On Windows, enter anything you would enter into cmd.exe (details follow). But to do the automatic path lookup on Windows, you need to do something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start iexplore.exe");
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start my.pdf");
```

which opens the pdf file with the associated viewer.

On linux, you can do anything you would do in a shell like Bash, but you cannot use bash builtins like the pipe operator. You can just start programs and pass arguments.

To start another Java instance on linux you could use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"java","-jar","myjar.jar"});
```

Use the absolute path to the java executable if it is not on the PATH.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you tell me what is the linux equivalent of `cmd /c start /b java -jar jarfile.jar`

Answer (score 3):

It is not platform independent. You need a version of the external command for each operating environment you're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

The `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is platform independent. `cmd /c` is. What are you expecting to get running `cmd /c` on Unix?

So, you have to hold platform specific commands if you want to make cross-platform program that runs external commands.

Comment: Thanks. What is the equivalent of `cmd /c start /b java -jar` in linux?

Answer (score 1):

It's platform dependent. Quoting a section of the [relevant javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29)(*emphasis mine*):

> This method checks that cmdarray is a valid operating system command. **Which commands are valid is system-dependent, but at the very least the command must be a non-empty list of non-null strings.**

Answer (score 1):

Of course not, you're executing a shell command. I don't suggest you doing this like that with Java unless you have no other cleaner way of doing what you want to do. It defeats Java's purpose of being portable.